# ThmxTheme Error

Tags: development, asp.net, http-module

I wrote a ASP.NET Handler module for sharepoint 2010 web application.
it is running .But I added this code, occured error
Code:

```
string tema = "/_catalogs/theme/Classic.thmx";
ThmxTheme tm = ThmxTheme.Open(SPContext.Current.Site, tema);
ThmxTheme.SetThemeUrlForWeb(SPContext.Current.Web, tm.ServerRelativeUrl);
```

Error:

```
<nativehr>0x80004005</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>Updates are currently disallowed on GET requests.  To allow updates on a GET, set the 'AllowUnsafeUpdates' property on SPWeb.
```

what is my error. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a good idea to use a handler for this. This code would run every time a page is called.
Instead use the WebProvisioned event to set the theme when a site is created.

@toni-frankola has an example on how to do this [here.](http://www.sharepointusecases.com/index.php/2010/09/automatically-apply-theme-to-a-sharepoint-foundation-2010-subsite/)

```
public override void WebProvisioned(SPWebEventProperties properties)
       {
           ThmxTheme theme = ThmxTheme.Open(properties.Web.Site, ThmxTheme.GetThemeUrlForWeb(properties.Web.ParentWeb));
           theme.ApplyTo(properties.Web, false);
           properties.Web.Update();
           base.WebProvisioned(properties);
       }
```

Comment: Thanks Anders.. This example is good for me. ASP.NET Handler module is not correct for this job. I prepared event receiver for web WebProvisioned eventhandler. it is working now. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

When you tries to save data to DB on GET request, SharePoint trims this operation by security reason. To solve this problem you can use [AllowUnsafeUpdates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite.allowunsafeupdates.aspx) property of SPWeb.

```
bool unsafeUpdates = SPContext.Current.Web.AllowUnsafeUpdates;
try
{
    SPContext.Current.Web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
    // your code
}
finally
{
    SPContext.Current.Web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = unsafeUpdates;
}
```